# DOM-Manipulation - display different elements, when text clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, npm, dom

I'm working on a little project to test some DOM manipulation.
I'm working on Todo list, where the user is able to create some lists named (like work, gym, finances, etc.) and then add some subtasks per category (click on work - shows subtask1, subtask2 etc. - when you click on gym should show gym's subtasks and so on.).

Now, I'm stuck where the user can click on the main tasks and show the subtasks separately each time the main is clicked.

It's almost all done via Javascript.

```
let index = 1;

function displayTasks() {
  const addButton = document.getElementById("addbutton");
  addButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    createDialogTasks();
  });
}

function createDialogTasks() {
  const content = document.getElementById("content");
  const dialog_tasks = document.createElement("dialog");

  const input_dialog_task = document.createElement("input");
  input_dialog_task.setAttribute("id", "input_create_task_name");
  input_dialog_task.setAttribute("type", "text");

  const create_task_name = document.createElement("button");
  create_task_name.setAttribute("id", "create-button");
  create_task_name.textContent = "Create";

  create_task_name.addEventListener("click", function () {
    createDialogButton(input_dialog_task, dialog_tasks);
  });

  const close_dialog_button = document.createElement("button");
  close_dialog_button.textContent = "Close";

  close_dialog_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    dialog_tasks.close();
  });

  content.appendChild(dialog_tasks);
  dialog_tasks.appendChild(input_dialog_task);
  dialog_tasks.appendChild(create_task_name);
  dialog_tasks.appendChild(close_dialog_button);
  dialog_tasks.showModal();
}

function displayTask(getTaskText) {
  const div_new_task = document.getElementById("added-tasks");

  const display_task_name = document.createElement("h1");
  display_task_name.setAttribute("data", index);
  display_task_name.textContent = getTaskText;
  display_task_name.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayTaskName(getTaskText);
  });

  const delete_task_button = document.createElement("button");
  delete_task_button.setAttribute("data", index);
  delete_task_button.textContent = "delete";

  delete_task_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    deleteTaskButton(display_task_name);
  });

  div_new_task.appendChild(display_task_name);
  div_new_task.appendChild(delete_task_button);
}

function createDialogButton(input_dialog_task, dialog_tasks) {
  if (input_dialog_task.value != "") {
    displayTask(input_dialog_task.value);
    dialog_tasks.close();
    console.log(input_dialog_task.value);
  } else {
    alert("Insert at least a char");
  }
  index++;
}

function displayTaskName(getTaskText) {
  const main_div = document.getElementById("main");
  const test = document.createElement("button");
  test.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const mainText = document.createElement("p");
    mainText.textContent = "test";
    main_div.appendChild(mainText);
  });
  test.textContent = "New Task";
  main_div.appendChild(test);
}

function deleteTaskButton(display_task_name) {
  const id_element_to_delete = display_task_name.getAttribute("data");
  const test = document.querySelectorAll(
    "[data='" + id_element_to_delete + "']"
  );
  test.forEach((item) => {
    item.outerHTML = "";
  });
}

export default displayTasks;
```

Here's the full javascript code.

Here's the HTML skeleton:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="\todo-list\dist\style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="header-text">My Todo List</div>
        <img
          src="/todo-list/src/assets/check-all.svg"
          alt=""
          class="header-logo"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="main-container">
        <nav class="sidebar">
          <div class="nav-text">
            <img
              src="/todo-list/src/assets/file-document-edit.svg"
              alt=""
              class="logo"
            />
            <p class="title">My Tasks</p>
            <button class="addbutton" id="addbutton">+</button>
          </div>
          <div class="added-tasks" id="added-tasks"></div>
          <button class="deletebutton">Delete</button>
        </nav>
        <main class="main" id="main"></main>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">Created by Veglia Marco &#9426;</div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

At the moment, when I click on the main task, once created, it shows a button to create subtasks. But they are shown all together.
How could I code it the way it is supposed to work?

I'm using NPM.

I thought about creating separate arrays for each element and then display them once clicked, but I don't that's the right way to think with DOMs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, i came up with a possible solution with the help of data-attributes.

Here's the full code, in case someone wants to code a Todo-List for reasons, and wants to check some functionality. (The CSS is far from finished, but the logic is, i hope, done.

At this point i can ask for suggestions in the code, or better ways to handle some situations, if you can.

```js
let index = 1;
let currentMain = null;

  const addButton = document.getElementById("addbutton");
  addButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    createDialogTasks();
  });

function createDialogTasks() {
  const content = document.getElementById("content");
  const dialog_tasks = document.createElement("dialog");

  const input_dialog_task = document.createElement("input");
  input_dialog_task.setAttribute("id", "input_create_task_name");
  input_dialog_task.setAttribute("type", "text");

  const create_task_name = document.createElement("button");
  create_task_name.setAttribute("id", "create-button");
  create_task_name.textContent = "Create";

  create_task_name.addEventListener("click", function () {
    createDialogButton(input_dialog_task, dialog_tasks);
  });

  const close_dialog_button = document.createElement("button");
  close_dialog_button.textContent = "Close";

  close_dialog_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    dialog_tasks.close();
  });

  content.appendChild(dialog_tasks);
  dialog_tasks.appendChild(input_dialog_task);
  dialog_tasks.appendChild(create_task_name);
  dialog_tasks.appendChild(close_dialog_button);
  dialog_tasks.showModal();
}

function displayTask(getTaskText) {
  const div_new_task = document.getElementById("added-tasks");

  const display_task_name = document.createElement("h1");
  const taskID = index;
  display_task_name.setAttribute("data", index);
  display_task_name.classList.add("task_name");
  display_task_name.textContent = getTaskText;

  display_task_name.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const taskID = display_task_name.getAttribute("data");
    const main = document.querySelector(`[data-main-for="${taskID}"]`);
    if (main) {
      if (currentMain) {
        currentMain.style.display = "none"; // Hide the current main
      }
      currentMain = main;
      currentMain.style.display = "block"; // Show the new current main
    } else {
      if (currentMain) {
        currentMain.style.display = "none"; // Hide the current main
      }
      currentMain = displayTaskName(taskID); // Set the new current main
    }

    const actives = document.querySelectorAll(".active");

    actives.forEach((active) => {
      active.classList.remove("active");
    });

    display_task_name.classList.add("active");

    if (display_task_name.classList.contains("active")) {
      display_task_name.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      display_task_name.style.display = "none";
    }
  });

  const delete_task_button = document.createElement("button");
  delete_task_button.setAttribute("data", index);
  delete_task_button.textContent = "delete";

  delete_task_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    deleteTaskButton(display_task_name);
  });

  div_new_task.appendChild(display_task_name);
  div_new_task.appendChild(delete_task_button);
  index++;
}

function createDialogButton(input_dialog_task, dialog_tasks) {
  if (input_dialog_task.value != "") {
    displayTask(input_dialog_task.value);
    dialog_tasks.close();
    console.log(input_dialog_task.value);
  } else {
    alert("Insert at least a char");
  }
}

function displayTaskName(taskID) {
  const main_container = document.getElementById("main-container");

  const main = document.createElement("main");
  main.setAttribute("data-main-for", taskID);
  main.style.display = "block"; // Show the new main

  const test = document.createElement("button");

  main.appendChild(test);

  test.addEventListener("click", function () {
    main.appendChild(createSubTask());
  });
  test.textContent = "New Task";

  main_container.appendChild(main);
  return main;
}

function deleteTaskButton(display_task_name) {
  const id_element_to_delete = display_task_name.getAttribute("data");
  const test = document.querySelectorAll(
    "[data='" + id_element_to_delete + "']"
  );
  test.forEach((item) => {
    item.outerHTML = "";
  });
}

function createSubTask() {
  const sub_task_dialog = document.createElement("dialog");

  const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");

  const sub_task_input = document.createElement("input");
  sub_task_input.setAttribute("type", "text");

  const calendar = document.createElement("input");
  calendar.setAttribute("type", "date");

  const close_sub_task_button = document.createElement("button");
  close_sub_task_button.textContent = "Close";

  close_sub_task_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    sub_task_dialog.close();
  });

  const submit_sub_task_button = document.createElement("button");
  submit_sub_task_button.textContent = "Submit";

  submit_sub_task_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const subTaskInfo = {
      isChecked: checkbox.checked,
      taskName: sub_task_input.value,
      date: calendar.value,
    };

    displaySubTaskInfo(subTaskInfo);

    sub_task_dialog.close();
  });

  sub_task_dialog.appendChild(checkbox);
  sub_task_dialog.appendChild(sub_task_input);
  sub_task_dialog.appendChild(calendar);
  sub_task_dialog.appendChild(submit_sub_task_button);
  sub_task_dialog.appendChild(close_sub_task_button);

  sub_task_dialog.show();

  return sub_task_dialog;
}

function displaySubTaskInfo(subTaskInfo) {
  if (currentMain) {
    const subTaskDiv = document.createElement("div");

    const dateElement = document.createElement("p");
    dateElement.setAttribute("id", "sub-date");
    dateElement.textContent = `Date: ${subTaskInfo.date}`;

    const nameElement = document.createElement("p");
    nameElement.setAttribute("id", "sub-name");
    nameElement.textContent = `Name: ${subTaskInfo.taskName}`;

    const checkboxElement = document.createElement("input");
    checkboxElement.setAttribute("id", "sub-check");
    checkboxElement.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkboxElement.checked = subTaskInfo.isChecked;

    const editButton = document.createElement("button");
    editButton.textContent = "Edit";
    editButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
      openEditSubTaskDialog(subTaskDiv, subTaskInfo);
    });

    const delete_sub_task = document.createElement("button");
    delete_sub_task.textContent = "Delete";
    delete_sub_task.addEventListener("click", function () {
      currentMain.removeChild(subTaskDiv);

      if (currentMain.querySelectorAll("div").length === 0) {
        const newTaskButton = currentMain.querySelector("button");
        if (newTaskButton) {
          newTaskButton.style.display = "block";
        }
      }
    });

    subTaskDiv.appendChild(checkboxElement);
    subTaskDiv.appendChild(nameElement);
    subTaskDiv.appendChild(dateElement);
    subTaskDiv.appendChild(editButton);
    subTaskDiv.appendChild(delete_sub_task);

    currentMain.appendChild(subTaskDiv);

    const subTasksExist = currentMain.querySelector("div");

    if (subTasksExist) {
      const newTaskButton = currentMain.querySelector("button");
      if (newTaskButton) {
        newTaskButton.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

function openEditSubTaskDialog(subTaskDiv, subTaskInfo) {
  const editSubTaskDialog = document.createElement("dialog");

  const editNameInput = document.createElement("input");
  editNameInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
  editNameInput.value = subTaskInfo.taskName;

  const editDateInput = document.createElement("input");
  editDateInput.setAttribute("type", "date");
  editDateInput.value = subTaskInfo.date;

  const editCheckboxInput = document.createElement("input");
  editCheckboxInput.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  editCheckboxInput.checked = subTaskInfo.isChecked;

  const saveButton = document.createElement("button");
  saveButton.textContent = "Save";
  saveButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    subTaskInfo.taskName = editNameInput.value;
    subTaskInfo.date = editDateInput.value;
    subTaskInfo.isChecked = editCheckboxInput.checked;

    subTaskDiv.querySelector(
      "#sub-date"
    ).textContent = `Date: ${subTaskInfo.date}`;
    subTaskDiv.querySelector("#sub-check").checked = subTaskInfo.isChecked;
    subTaskDiv.querySelector("#sub-name").textContent = subTaskInfo.taskName;

    editSubTaskDialog.close();
  });

  const cancelButton = document.createElement("button");
  cancelButton.textContent = "Cancel";
  cancelButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    editSubTaskDialog.close();
  });

  editSubTaskDialog.appendChild(editCheckboxInput);
  editSubTaskDialog.appendChild(editNameInput);
  editSubTaskDialog.appendChild(editDateInput);
  editSubTaskDialog.appendChild(saveButton);
  editSubTaskDialog.appendChild(cancelButton);

  document.body.appendChild(editSubTaskDialog);

  editSubTaskDialog.showModal();
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "OpenSansLight";
  src: url("fonts/fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot");
  src: url("fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot?#iefix")
      format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("/todo-list/src/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.svg#OpenSansLight") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: OpenSansLight;
  font-size: 20px;
}

body {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100wh;
  height: 100vh;
}

#content {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1fr 2fr;
  height: 400px;
  width: 800px;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 0.8fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.header-text {
  text-align: right;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.main-container {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  height: 48.5vh;
}

.nav-text {
  margin: 5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.16fr 1fr 1.4fr;
}

.addbutton {
  width: 27px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  scale: 0.8;
  border: none;
}

.addbutton:hover {
  background-color: green;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.addbutton:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 1px #666;
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.deletebutton {
  margin: 7px;
}

.deletebutton:hover {
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.deletebutton:active {
  background-color: #df5454;
  box-shadow: 0 1px #666;
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.active {
  background-color: orange;
}

.task_name:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.sub-tasks-div {
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="header-text">My Todo List</div>
        <img
          src="/todo-list/src/assets/check-all.svg"
          alt=""
          class="header-logo"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="main-container" id="main-container">
        <nav class="sidebar">
          <div class="nav-text">
            <img
              src="/todo-list/src/assets/file-document-edit.svg"
              alt=""
              class="logo"
            />
            <p class="title">My Tasks</p>
            <button class="addbutton" id="addbutton">+</button>
          </div>
          <div class="added-tasks" id="added-tasks"></div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">Created by Veglia Marco &#9426;</div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks.